Simplifying this specific merge of dataframes?
I'm struggling to get pandas merge, join, or concat to do what I need, so I wrote a merge using for loops (I know). Sady this is a lot of data and it's simply taking way too long. How would I simplify this using pandas dataframe operations?
Here's my code:
import pandas as pd

# grab avg dyads data
with open('C:/Users/user/Desktop/NarrativeData/parcel_avgs_dyad_and_sub_final.csv', mode='r+') as file:
    dyadAvgsHeader = file.readline().strip('\n').split(',')
    dyadAvgs = pd.read_csv(file, names=dyadAvgsHeader)

parcel_names = dyadAvgsHeader[8:]

# wide to long 
iscLong = pd.melt(dyadAvgs, id_vars=[dyadAvgsHeader[1], dyadAvgsHeader[2]], value_vars=parcel_names, var_name='parcels', value_name='brain_corr')
print(iscLong)

# grab exit survey data
with open('completed_exit_surveys.csv', mode='r+') as file:
    exitSurveyHeader = file.readline().strip('\n').split(',')
    exitSurvey = pd.read_csv(file, names=exitSurveyHeader)

# add questions columns 
questions = exitSurveyHeader[4:]
for x in range(len(questions)):
    iscLong[questions[x]] = 0

iscLong.to_csv('iscLong.csv')

# for loop hell here
for i in range(len(exitSurvey)):
    # find indexes of columns with matching dyads and subjects
    dyad_match = iscLong['dyad'] == exitSurvey.loc[i, "dyad"]
    subj_match = iscLong['subject'] == exitSurvey.loc[i, "subject"]
    index_match = list(iscLong[dyad_match & subj_match].index)
    print(index_match)
    

    for index in index_match:
        for q in questions:
            iscLong[q][index] = exitSurvey[q][i]

# output
iscLong.to_csv('merged_data.csv')

Thank you!

Add minimal in input date to the post

5 or 10 lines of data to make this code reproducible will help a lot.
